# Huawei push kit service doesn't send data message just on one topic

Tags: android, push-notification, message, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm using the Huawei push kit services.

I can't figure it out, I have subscribed to multiple topics and receive data messages on each of them except one, the 'Sport' topic. I'm using postman to do some checks and send the messages, and as we see in the image below, the subscription is successful.

The code for subscribing is

```
HmsMessaging.getInstance(this@MyActivity).subscribe("stiri")
```

[image]

And the message is successfully send
[image]

The only time I receive a message is if I unsubscribe and subscribe 2 or 3 times to the 'Sport' topic.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the notes (in italics) below and make sure your implementations meet the requirements or limitations. Since only the "Sport" topic doesn't work well, you can try the followings:

1. Double-check Sport topic settings and processes are the same as other topics.
2. Try to delete the Sport topic and create it again.
3. If the above 1 & 2 cannot solve the problem, please share your APP ID, Push Message content and time (time zone, date), logcat logs, developer ID, Postman-related screenshots, etc. so we can take a deeper look into it.

Here is the limitation of the Push Kit topics:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-topic-based-sending-0000001050040114

NOTE

. Topic messages are applied to transmit information that is publicly available, such as weather and temperature.

. Topic-based messaging does not limit the number of subscriptions for each topic. However, the function in Push Kit has the following restrictions:

. Each app can subscribe to a maximum of 2000 topics.

. A message can contain a maximum of 100 topics.

. For Huawei devices running EMUI 10.0 or later, the version of HMS Core (APK) must be 3.0.0 or later. For Huawei devices running EMUI earlier than 10.0, the version of HMS Core (APK) must be 4.0.3 or later. HMS Core (APK) of a later version supplements the functions that are missing in EMUI of an earlier version.

Comment: Hi @Zinna. I tested it multiple times this week and apparently now it works just fine, for all the topics including the 'Sport' one. Maybe it was a temporary problem with the HMS service. Thanks for your interest and the reply.

Comment: @Vlad.mir No problem, Vlad, glad it works for you now. Let me know if you need help in the future.

Comment: Hey @Zinna, when you have time can you take a look at this problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/75098448/3288058

Comment: @Vlad.mir sure, will take a look and respond there.