# Can't enable Huawei Push Kit from developer

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I keep getting this error when I try to enable the Push Kit, I tried initializing even in the app with the HMS Toolkit.

[image]

For test I enabled the Push Kit on other projects, 2/4 let me enable it, and the others didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official claim for this issue. Please review.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faq-0000001050042183

What can I do if Push Kit fails to be enabled?

1. Check whether Push Kit has been enabled for your app. If so, an error will be reported if you enable it again.
2. Check whether your app has been uploaded via another account. If it has, delete or transfer the app from the account. For details about how to transfer the app, please refer to App Transfer Operation Guide.
3. Check whether an app exists in your project. If not, create one, and enable Push Kit. If there is an app in your project, but a message is displayed, indicating that no app exists, when you enable Push Kit, check whether the app with the same package name in another project has been operated, such as claimed or deleted. If so, disable Push Kit in another project and then enable it for the current project.
4. If the problem persists, please contact the support here - developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/contactUs

Comment: Thanks for the response, what worked was turning the push kit off from the switch in 'Project settings' and then going back to the Push Kit page and Enabling it from the button

Comment: @Vlad.mir Glad it's working for you now. Let me know if need any further assistance.